# NgFor only showing first value in Array

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular-material

I'm building a dynamic menu in Angular and my menu is only showing the first value in the array.

How can I make it dynamically show all of the values in the array? What am I doing wrong?

Array is set in the local storage

**Array Code**

```
FunctionNames: string[];
FunctionsActive: boolean[];

    this.FunctionNames = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('FunctionNames'));
```

**View.component.html**

```
   <!--Context Right Click Menu-->
  <mat-menu #contextMenu="matMenu" #contextMenu2="matMenu">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let function of FunctionNames">
    <ng-template matMenuContent let-action="action">
        <button mat-menu-item (click)="onContextMenuAction(action)">{{function}}</button>
    </ng-template>
  </ng-container>
  </mat-menu>
```

**View.component.ts**

```
    onContextMenu(event: MouseEvent, action: ViewDataSource) {
      event.preventDefault();
      this.contextMenuPosition.x = event.clientX + 'px';
      this.contextMenuPosition.y = event.clientY + 'px';
      this.contextMenu.menuData = { action: action };
      this.contextMenu.menu.focusFirstItem('mouse');
      this.contextMenu.openMenu();
    }

    onContextMenuAction(action: ViewDataSource ) {
      this.launchService.launchAction(parseInt(action[0]), parseInt(action[3]));
    }
```

**Updated HTML Code from Comment**

```
   <mat-menu #contextMenu="matMenu" #contextMenu2="matMenu">
        <ng-container>
          <div mat-menu-item *ngFor="let function of FunctionNames"> {{function}}
        <div matMenuContent *ngFor="let action of action;">
            <button mat-menu-item (click)="onContextMenuAction(action)">{{function}}</button>
        </div>
        </div>
      </ng-container>
      </mat-menu>
```

**Updated Action Dataset**

```
      onContextMenuAction(action: ViewDataSource ) {


      this.launchService.launchAction(parseInt(action[0]), parseInt(action[3]));

    }
```

**Updated Context Menu HTML**

```
        onContextMenu(event: MouseEvent, action: ViewDataSource) {
      event.preventDefault();
      this.contextMenuPosition.x = event.clientX + 'px';
      this.contextMenuPosition.y = event.clientY + 'px';
      this.contextMenu.menuData = { action: action };
      this.contextMenu.menu.focusFirstItem('mouse');
      this.contextMenu.openMenu();
      console.log(this.FunctionNames);
    }

    onContextMenuAction(action: ViewDataSource ) {
    console.log('clicked');

      // this.launchService.launchAction(this.line.targetActionTag.value, this.line.targetActionType);
      // tslint:disable-next-line: radix
      this.launchService.launchAction(parseInt(action[0]), parseInt(action[3]));
    //   debugger;

    }
```

Comment: can you share the code where your array is defined?

Comment: @ThorstenRintelen just updated... I'm pulling the array from a service, and setting it in the local storage. But for whatever reason I'm only getting the first value in the menu, but in the console, I can see the entire Array

Comment: Can you create a plunker ?

Comment: In `let action of action`, where does the `of action` come from?

Comment: action is a variable name from an external datasource component  service that's a local json object ...
        this.dataSource = new ViewDataSource(this.actionService);

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using this code.Hope this will solve your problem

In .ts you can store the action object like

```
this.dataSource = new ViewDataSource(this.actionService);
```

and in .html (Assume `this.dataSource` will store the actual action object that you need to access)

```
<mat-menu #contextMenu="matMenu" #contextMenu2="matMenu">
    <div mat-menu-item *ngFor="let function of FunctionNames">
      <ng-template matMenuContent>
        <button (click)="onContextMenuAction(dataSource)">{{function}}</button>
      </ng-template>
  </div>
  </mat-menu>
```

Please confirm what you want to access in the click event

Comment: this does help I can now see the different items in the menu array but for some reason I'm not able to access the button (click) function....

Here's my updated code in snippet

@DhirajSingh

Comment: Just updated the code in the snippet under **Updated Code** .... my code is not reaching the (click) function

Comment: What you want to pass in the click event.As per the updated code there is a extra  *ngFor="let action of action;" is there which seems wrong.Can you please create a plunker ? I have also updated my answer

Comment: the plunker probably won't work.. being that the data is in my local environment.. so I can't replicate it .... but yes I am trying to pass in data from an action json object into the click event... my issue is that I'm unable to reach this click event even though my menu items are working

Comment: The data which you want to pass in click event.Its not available in the ngFor on the menu items.Can you please specify what is the action json object and how its getting created.

Comment: just updated the action json object.... it's a object that has a set of values that I am passing in order to run the click function that I added

Comment: You have updated the use of action.What I am asking the action you are trying to access from where we'll get it inside the loop and what king of value will be there in the action with one example.

Comment: the values are strings and I'm suppose to be using it when the menu is dynamically created. right now I'm unable to access the NgFor loop for action the way it's currently written

Comment: just updated my code to include the context menu HTML

Comment: Please tell me how the value of the action string are connected to each menu items .

Comment: action is a variable name from an external datasource component  service that's a local json object ...
        this.dataSource = new ViewDataSource(this.actionService);

Comment: But how they are connected to each menu item that i want to know.

Comment: Basically I’m using a value in the array of actions, in order to run the function that corresponds to a menu item. That’s the goal for the future but right now I just want to run the values from the action object first...the connections to the menu items aren’t important at the moment

Comment: If the connection is not important then how we can identify on click of which menu item which action we need to pass OR do we need to pass same action in every menu click then we can simply keep the action object in a variable  and pass it in click event

Comment: Yes the second option.. passing in the same action for every menu click

Comment: I think I am close but it's still not running the onContextMenuAction function correctly.. if you look in the code you'll see that the           this.launchService.launchAction(parseInt(action[0]), parseInt(action[3])); line has two parameters... that's where the action object comes in .... so I have to use that action object to get those array values

Comment: It seems there is a problem in storing the action object value.Can please put the content of action object the I will be able to help you further.

Comment: yup the action object looks like this

action = { value1: 0, value2: 1, value3: 2 ... etc)

Comment: You can directly access the action object in the click handler . There you can put console and check the action object.No need to send from HTML

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219576/discussion-between-kjamp-and-dhiraj-singh).